# In an electrocyclic reaction with two pi bonds that result in a trans product, is a mix of products seen?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, pericyclic

[image]

When I look at the highest occupied molecular orbital, the two methyl groups will end up being trans to each other. I realized based on which conrotation direction both methyl groups take that two different trans products are formed that do not overlap but the lecture only gave one of these products. Am I missing a concept here or missing something obvious?

Comment: The"other" *trans*-dimethylcyclobutene is the enantiomer of the one you've drawn above. The 2 *trans* products are formed in equal amounts to yield  a racemic mixture.